# How to remove placeholder on autocomplete? (Input field, material ui)

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, autocomplete, frontend

I use an input field from the material ui library.

[image]

When you focus on the input, the pseudo-filler moves animatedly to the top of the input.

If we have 2 inputs and we want to autocomplete those inputs, the pseudo-complete of the second input will overlay the value that is substituted from the autocomplete.
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Removing those placeholders is not an option.
Maybe catch values during autocompleteor directly throw in values from autocomplete?

Comment: can you not use shrink? InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}